# What is the concept of an Parse server project with an express application?

Tags: parse-platform, graphql, parse-server

Sorry if the title makes you confuse. I mean, I'm working with the Parse Server. My job is creating an express js app on the client-side. I'm a little bit confused with the concept of Parse server. It includes 3 part:

- A parse server
- A Dashboard
- An express application I develop from this SDK. [Javascript SDK](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS/releases/tag/2.19.0)

But sometimes, it makes me confuse that if I doing right. Sometimes, I don't know where should I put the code on the Parse Server or the express app. For example, when I interacted with graphQL, I create the schema and define the could function in the Parse server, but I can't call it in the express app, and when I read the document([here](https://docs.parseplatform.org/graphql/guide/#using-expressjs)), I wonder that should I put the schema and define the cloud Code in the express app, but I still think it doesn't right.

Comment: You might want to choose a frontend framework such as React, Angular, etc. Your Express.js app will only serve the static files that you need for your frontend. The frontend will connect to Parse using the SDK.

Comment: Can you let me know more about the role of that three-part, As I think, the Parse server is the server, the Dashboard is the FE that you can use to using all service of Parse, and the JS SDK is the SDK you interacted to your application to connect with the Parse Server, right?

Comment: Parse Server will automatically generates an API for you on top of a MongoDB or Postgres database. Parse Dashboard helps you to manage your data and other features on your backend. Parse JS SDK is the library that makes it easier for you to connect your frontend to the Parse API. That's your backend and how Parse helps you on creating that. Now you need to create your frontend. Recently the most common use-case for creating a web frontend is through a JS framework such as React or Angular or Vue, etc. They make it easier to manipulate your HTML elements and manage your app state.